# How to classify a variable based on the value in the row above it in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with four columns. I would like to create a new column where the value depends on the other column row above. For example, I have a data set like this:

| Day | Precipitation | Condition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | Wet |
| 2 | 0 | Dry |
| 3 | 3 | Wet |

I would like the final product to look something like this?

| Day | Precipitation | Condition | Day Before |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | Wet |  |
| 2 | 0 | Dry | Wet |
| 3 | 3 | Wet | Dry |

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate('Day Before' = lag(Condition))
    
  Day Precipitation Condition Day Before
1   1             3       Wet       <NA>
2   2             2       Dry        Wet
3   3             3       Wet        Dry
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain R approach:

To define the `Day Before` column , add `NA` to the beginning of the `Condition` column (`df$Condition`) and remove the last element in that vector (`df$condition[-length(df$condition)`).

```
df$DayBefore <- c(NA,df$Condition[-length(df$Condition)])

df
    Day Percepitation Condition DayBefore
1   1             3       wet      <NA>
2   2             0       dry       wet
3   3             3       wet       dry
```